# Why is ΔH (enthalpy)=Σreactants-Σproducts and not Σproducts-Σreactants?

Tags: enthalpy

I was told that ΔH=Σreactants-Σproducts in regards to finding the enthalpy, given average bond enthalpies.

Why is the case? It seems counterintuitive, because of the delta, which would imply ΔH=Σproducts-Σreactants.

Is this the case, because of the fact that for breaking the bonds in the products energy is required, while for forming the bonds in the products, releases energy and that enthalpy is equal to the heat released?